# Importing Custom Module error

Tags: python-3.x

[image: Module which I made and saved in the library of python]

[image: Error]

Hi
I am trying to import a custom module in python script. But I am getting the error that the attribute I defined in the Module script in not defined, infact I defined it ? Why I am getting this error constantly.

Comment: Post code, not pictures of code.

Comment: when you click on Error and Module....python links you would be able to see.